# Open directory on network in PhpStorm

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

I'm working from a windows 7 PC and my source code is on an Ubuntu PC. I have a shared folder on the Ubuntu computer that I can browse from my Windows computer.

I'm trying to open this directory in PhpStorm via File -> Open Directory. The problem is I can't seem to browse the network using the File browser (shown below) PhpStorm provides. Also entering a path like \my-dev-pc\projects\php\cms just causes it to open my C:\ directory.

[image: PhpStorm File browser]

Any ideas on how I can solve this? Perhaps some configuration that allows PhpStorm to use the default Windows Explorer file browser?

Comment: Better work with local copy of your files and then setup Deployment so they automatically get uploaded/copied to your remote location -- much less hassle and smooth operation (this IDE requires really fast access to source files otherwise may introduce lags and random short freezes).

Comment: P.S. But you can work directly over network if desired (you have been warned!) -- but for that you have to assign a letter for your network path (so that on Windows it looks like another drive) because IDE does not support UNC paths, at all.

Answer (score 2):

Since your project files are on network, you should follow below steps:

file > new project from existing source.

Then you will get a pop up with options for connecting to remote machine/server using ftp/sftp.

Select that and then enter your credentials.

There is also an option to select files which are accesile via network.

This should help you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

Map network share as a disk drive. :)

[Reference](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207067835-How-to-open-project-from-the-network-share)

[Map a network drive in Windows guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/map-a-network-drive-in-windows-29ce55d1-34e3-a7e2-4801-131475f9557d)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remap it via

```
$ net use z: \\drive.fulldomain.com\c$ /persistent:yes
```