# PhpStorm: Open directory on local network in Windows

Tags: phpstorm

If possible, how to open project directory located on other PC? For example: `//server/test`

```
PhpStorm 2018.1.2
Windows 10
```

Comment: Do not. This IDE will not handle it well .. as it requires fast access to source files ... and any network access will be noticeable slower. Better make a local copy and then setup auto-copy to the network location. **P.S.** 2018.2 is not available .. latest stable is 2018.1.3 only.

Comment: yes I meant 2018.1.2 :) 
Thank you for the response

Comment: Here is about auto-copying and deployment in general: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deployments+in+PhpStorm **P.S.** You can assign a drive letter to such network path (mount it) and access it from PhpStorm that way ... but as I have said -- better not to work via network directly. Not everything will work that smooth ...

Comment: Workaround solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30893905/8696548

Answer (score 3, accepted):

creating projects on non-mapped network shares accessed via UNC paths is not currently supported; you can follow the related request in our tracker: [IDEA-123273](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-123273).

You can map your network drive to be able to create a project. But we normally discourage our users from storing projects on remote drives... In general, having project and configuration files on a local dick is essential for the best IDE experience. All IDE functionality is based on the index of the project files which PhpStorm builds when the project is loaded and updates on the fly as you edit your code. To provide efficient coding assistance, PhpStorm needs to re-index code fast, which requires fast access to project files. The latter can be ensured only for local files, that is, files that are stored on you hard disk and are accessible through the file system.

Moreover, the fsnotifier tool we use to synchronize the IDE virtual file system with external changes doesn't support remote drives, so you might have problems synchronizing files created externally, outside of PhpStorm, have issues showing files/folders in Project tree, etc.

The suggested solution is storing a copy of your project locally and synchronizing it with a remote drive using Deployment features (see https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deployments+in+PhpStorm)